# Computing limit of an energy of a probability measure

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, calculus-of-variations

For $c\in (0,1)$, consider the probability density
$$f_c := \frac{1-c^2}{1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)}.$$

> **Goal.** Evaluate the limit as $c\rightarrow 1$ of
> $$E(f_c) := \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\log(f_c)f_c dx - \pi\|f_c\|_{\dot{H}^{-\frac12}}^2,$$
> where $\dot{H}^{-\frac12}$ denotes the usual homogeneous Sobolev norm of index $-\frac12$. Alternatively, one can write
> $$\pi\|f_c\|_{\dot{H}^{-\frac12}}^2 = -\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\log|\sin(\pi x)|f_c(x)f_c(y)dxdy + \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\log|\sin(\pi y)|dy.$$
> For variational reasons, I know that $E(f_c)>0$.

I know that for $k\ge 1$, the $k$-th Fourier coefficient $\hat{f}_c(k) = c$. This implies that
$$\pi\|f_c\|_{\dot{H}^{-\frac12}}^2 = 2\pi\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{c^{2k}}{2\pi k} = -\log(1-c^2), \tag{1}$$
where I've used the power series for $\log(1+z)$ to obtain the final equality.

Now inserting the definition of $f_c$ and using that $\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}f_c=1$, I can compute
$$\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\log(f_c)f_cdx = \log(1-c^2) - (1-c^2)\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\frac{\log\Big(1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)\Big)}{1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)}dx. \tag{2}$$
Now inserting (1) and (2) into the RHS for $E(f_c)$ yields
$$E(f_c) = 2\log(1-c^2) - (1-c^2)\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\frac{\log\Big(1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)\Big)}{1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)}dx. $$
I am stuck with what to do with the second term. Naively, I might try to write
$$1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x) = (1-c)^2 + 2c[1-\cos(2\pi x)]$$
and pull out a factor of $(1-c)^2$ to write
\begin{multline}
(1-c^2)\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\frac{\log\Big(1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)\Big)}{1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)}dx = 2\log(1-c) \\
+ (1-c^2)\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\frac{\log\Big(1+\frac{2c[1-\cos(2\pi x)]}{(1-c)^2}\Big)}{1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)}dx.
\end{multline}
The first term is OK, because I can combine it with $2\log(1-c^2)$. But the second term, I am still stuck. My guess is to try some sort of Taylor expansion of $1-\cos(2\pi x)$ when $|x|\lesssim 1-c$, but not sure how to make this work.

Comment: $$\int\frac{\log\Big(1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)\Big)}{1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)}\,dx$$ doest exist (even if it is a monster). The key problem if the evaluation at the bounds.

Comment: OK, but I am not interested in an exact formula for the antiderivative, only for the limit as $c\rightarrow 1$ after you normalize by $(1-c^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

If we naively assume that we can pass the limit inside the integral, the result would be
$$\lim_{c\to 0} E(f_c) = 0.$$
Notice that for $c$ small enough,
$$c^2<|1-2c|=\inf_{x\in(-1/2,1/2)} |1-2c\cos(2\pi x)|<|1-2c\cos(2\pi x)|.$$
Hence, we have for $c<1/4,$
$$|c^2 + 1-2c\cos(2\pi x)|\ge ||1-2c\cos(2\pi x)|- c^2|=|1-2c\cos(2\pi x)|- c^2\ge 1-2c-c^2>7/16.$$
Additionally, again for $c<1/4$,
$$|c^2 + 1-2c\cos(2\pi x)|\le (1+c)^2\le 25/16.$$
Let me denote $f(x)=c^2 + 1-2c\cos(2\pi x)$. Thus, we have $7/16\le f(x)\le 25/16$ and
\begin{aligned}
\frac{|\log\Big(1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)\Big)|}{|1+c^2-2c\cos(2\pi x)|}dx &\le \frac{16}{7}\left( \log f(x)1_{f(x)\ge 1}(x)   +\log(1/f(x))1_{f(x)<1}(x)\right) \\ &\le  \frac{16}{7}(\log(25/6)1_{f(x)\ge 1}(x) +\log(16/7)   1_{f(x)<1}(x)).
\end{aligned}
The latter quantity is in $L^1(0,1/2)$ and thus by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, we may pass the limit inside to find that $E(f_c)\to 0$ as $c\to 0$.

Comment: Grr...I am sorry. As $c\rightarrow 0$ is a misprint. It should be as $c\rightarrow 1$. The other limit is not interesting for my purposes.

Comment: You should probably make another question then for the limit $c\to 1$ since it is a significant edit.

Comment: I agree. It's obnoxious when the OP significantly changes the question after it was answered.

Comment: @Gonçalo People make mistakes. I apologized to Dispersion, and I fail to see how you were harmed.